# ngx-swiper-wrapper with multiple configurations for different sliders

Tags: angular, carousel, swiper.js

I am using the [ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper) npm package to implement 2 sliders with different configurations on the same page of a SPA site.
Both swiper sliders are created in different components:
brands.component and testimonials.component.

My brands template is as follows:

```
<swiper [config]="BRANDS_SWIPER_CONFIG" [(index)]="index">
     <div class="swiper-slide">slide</div>
</swiper>
```

My testimonials template is as follows:

```
<swiper [config]="TESTIMONIALS_SWIPER_CONFIG" [(index)]="index">
     <div class="swiper-slide">              
     <div class="testimonial-item text-center"></div>
</swiper>
```

my **app.module**

```
import { SwiperModule, SWIPER_CONFIG, SwiperConfigInterface } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';

const BRANDS_SWIPER_CONFIG: SwiperConfigInterface = {
   direction: 'horizontal',
   slidesPerView: 4,
   autoplay: { delay: 3000 },
   breakpoints:{ 640: { slidesPerView: 2 } }
 };

 const TESTIMONIALS_SWIPER_CONFIG: SwiperConfigInterface = {
      direction: 'horizontal',
      slidesPerView: 1,
 };

 @NgModule({
   providers: [
     CurrencyPipe,
     { provide: SWIPER_CONFIG, useValue: BRANDS_SWIPER_CONFIG },
     { provide: SWIPER_CONFIG, useValue: TESTIMONIALS_SWIPER_CONFIG }
  ],
```

The TESTIMONIALS_SWIPER_CONFIG overwrites my BRANDS_SWIPER_CONFIG, how is it possible to configure so that my testimonial template takes the settings of the TESTIMONIALS_SWIPER_CONFIG

Comment: You're overwriting the `SWIPER_CONFIG` in the app module by providing it twice. Looks like providing the configs like that isn't going to work. Maybe, move the configs into the components that are using them.

Comment: EDIT: it seems to have worked. Before it was doing the same but I had not renamed my useValue variables within providers.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add the below mentioned script and link tag in index.html:

```
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.min.css">
```

2.Add the below given function in '.html' file of respective swiper slider component.

```
      <div class="brands-container swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">              
                        <div class="brands-item text-center"></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-container swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                  <div class="swiper-slide">              
                        <div class="testimonial-item text-center"></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

3.Add the below given function in '.ts' file of respective swiper slider component.

```
      declare var Swiper: any;

      ngOnInit() {
            var mySwiper = new Swiper('.testimonial-container .swiper-container', {
                  direction: 'horizontal',
                  loop: true,
                  effect: 'slide',
                  observer: true, 
                  observeParents: true
            });
            var mySwiper = new Swiper('.brands-container .swiper-container', {
                  direction: 'horizontal',
                  loop: true,
                  effect: 'slide',
                  observer: true, 
                  observeParents: true
            });
      }
```